# Call Preference from SQLite DB Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, preferenceactivity

I am developing a dictionary app. I have the following code which show 20 most recent history word.

```
public List<Bean> getHistoryWords() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + HISTORY_NAME +
                " WHERE " + STATUS + " ORDER BY " + STATUS + " DESC LIMIT 20" ;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        List<Bean> wordList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String english = cursor.getString(1);
            String bangla = cursor.getString(2);
            String status = cursor.getString(3);
            wordList.add(new Bean(id, english, bangla, status));
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return wordList;
    }
```

I would like to provide an option for user to change the number of history item from `LIMIT 20` to `LIMIT 50` or `LIMIT 100` through `Preferences`.

I follow [this tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-tutorial-preferencescreen-preferenceactivity-preferencefragment), but I was stuck in "5) Saving/reading data". I tried to put the `SharedPreferences` under `getHistoryWords`, but I got error `cannot resolve getBaseContext`.

```
public List<Bean> getHistoryWords() {
    SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

Where should I put the code?

Comment: Create separate class to save and get the data from Shared Preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simplest way for it.
First, create YourAppName , that extends `Application`
Declare `Context` as static and init it on Application 's onCreate method,

```
public YourApp extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        YourApp.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {    
        return YourApp.context;
    }
}
```

declare YourApp in Manifest.xml

`android:name="com.yourpackagename.app.YourApp"` in application tag,

Now, you can get for Context, every where you need like this,

```
 YourApp.getAppContext()
```

I hope this will help for you.